# Flutter Dio package download path

Tags: dart, flutter

My main goal is to download a file from a link and then save it to the phone's internal storage so that it'll be accessible through the phone's file manager. I'm currently trying out [Dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) package by running the example [code](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/download.dart) given in the package's repo. Upon running the program, I ran into a path problem. When I used `./example/flutter.png` as the download path, `I/flutter (10109): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = './example/flutter.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)` shows up. And when I used `(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path` which produces a `String` with the value of: `/data/user/0/com.example.downloadexample/app_flutter` as the path, no error showed up, but the file wasn't there. I tried different variation of the latter path, but with no success. Can someone help me with this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use http package, not the Dio,  the code:

```
Future<String> fetchNetFileToDoc(String url, String filename) async {
  final path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File docFile = File('$path/$filename');
    if(await docFile.exists()){
    print( '${docFile.path} exits');
    return docFile.path;
  }

  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  // todo - check status
  await docFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes, flush: true);
  return docFile.path;
}
```

if I invoke this method, like: `fetchNetFileToDoc('http://a.com/a.mp3', 'a.mp3')`
it shows the same error:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path= 'Direcotry: '/data/user/0/com.example.master_lu/app_flutter'/a.mp3' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

But if I use getTemporaryDirectory(), change code to this:

```
Future<String> fetchNetFileToTemp(String url, String filename) async {
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path;
  File tempFile = File('$tempPath/$filename');
  if(await tempFile.exists()){
    print( '${tempFile.path} exits');
    return tempFile.path;
  }

  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  // todo - check status
  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes, flush: true);
  return tempFile.path;
}
```

That's ok, it works with the internal storage. Save the file into the `data/user/0/com.example.master_lu/cache/a.mp3`
The master_lu is the name of my project.

The latest=> I sovle my problem, `await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` return `Future<Directory>`

so, here is the right code:

```
Future<String> fetchNetFileToDoc(String url, String filename) async {
  final docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String docPath = docDir.path;
  File docFile = File('$docPath/$filename');
    if(await docFile.exists()){
    print( '${docFile.path} exits');
    return docFile.path;
  }

  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  // todo - check status
  await docFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes, flush: true);
  return docFile.path;
}
```